# QML crashes on iOS when using StackView and VideoOutput

Tags: ios, qt, qml

I'm trying to switch to another qml page using **StackView** but it always crashes on **iOS** when I use **VideoOutput**

error I get:

> program received signal -111,
> thread:41744;00:a0e5358002000000;01:0000000000000000;02:a0e5a7680d000000;03:00ad348002000000;

If i remove VideoOutput from my code it switches to the next qml page without issue.

I'm guessing that iOS doesn't want videooutput processing in the background of the app

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true

    StackView {
        id: stack
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        stack.replace("page2.qml")
    }

}
```

**page2.qml**

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtMultimedia

Item {

      RoundButton {
          id: capture
          text: "CRASHES WHEN I CLICK THIS BUTTON - go to page 3"
          z: 2
          onClicked: {
              stack.replace("page3.qml")
          }
      }

      Rectangle
      {
          id: bgRect
          color: "white"
          anchors.fill: videoOutput
      }

      Camera
      {
          id:camera
          active: true
      }

      CaptureSession {
          camera: camera
          videoOutput: videoOutput
      }

      VideoOutput
      {
          id: videoOutput
          width: Screen.width
          height: Screen.height
      }

}
```

**page3.qml**

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Item {

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    Button {
        id: clicky2
        text: "Go back to page2"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        onClicked: {
            stack.replace("page2.qml")
        }
    }

}
```

It doesn't crash if I remove VideoOutput

I have tried to set camera.active: false but this also doesn't work

Nothing in the manual about being able to disable VideoOutput

Comment: Would this be iOS 16? We are seeing similar problems, but, no solutions atm. The only workarounds we have are either (1) avoid destroying and creating the Camera object by moving it out of the StackView (i.e. it's the Camera that's the problem not the VideoOutput), (2) attempt to call camera.stop() in hope that the camera will release it's resources properly before you pop it off the page.

Comment: yes im using ios 16.2

Comment: Has this bug been reported? Also, a backtrace would be very helpful if you can get it.

Comment: Its been reported: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-112352 and listed as fixed in QT 6.5.1
Otherwise I had to move camera outside of stackview